# Send an sms to ESME from restcomm SMSC

Tags: sms, smpp, restcomm

I am working with restcom SMSC. I am able establish connection with an ESME node. Restcomm SMSC is acting as smpp server in the connection. Currently, I can receive the message from ESME node. I want to send a message to ESME node. How can  this be achieved? What parameter needs to be passed in destination address of message?